# "each"/"map" on array results in "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it" in create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?, sporadically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button which is sending a get request over XHR to a specific action in a rails server.
This action calls a function I defined in the model "Category". This function does something like x=Category.subcategories, and in the next line something like x.map(&:id), or x.each {|x| y << x.id}. (Category has_many :subcategories). In my development environment this works for 1-10 clicks on this button, but then stops working for the following reason:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?
```

With the following dump:

```
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:142:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:355:in `respond_to?'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `map'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:369:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/app/models/category.rb:24:in `fetch_prices_grouped_by_date'
C:/MyApp/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:103:in `show'
```

Restarting the server fixes the problem for the next 1-10 clicks and then it reappears.
When debugging that line (on NetBeans IDE, ruby-debug-ide-0.3.1), I get (after crossing the 1-10 "good clicks") to the method_missing (method="map", self="{Array, 23 elements}"), and if I try to expand the watch on variable x, the debug server crashes.
Following the advice of [this post](http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2009/01/22/bug-of-the-day-nilinclude-error-with-create_time_zone_conversion_attribute/), I edited my environment.rb and turned class caching on:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

and the problem is solved. However, it is very annoying to restart the server after each change in code, and I was wondering if anyone has an idea of what is going on, why changing the cache_classes solves it, and if there is any other workaround that doesn't carry the pain of restarting after every edit.

I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

Many thanks,
Amit

**EDIT:**

OK, so after some more debugging I realize it fails on having skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes set to nil for some reason in create_time_zone_conversion_attribute? method (active_record/attribute_methods.rb).

Found [this article](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1290) after some research. 
Adding:

```
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = []
```

to the model doesn't work.

Replacing in environment.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

with

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

doesn't work for me either, as I get "stack level too deep" with:

```
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:237:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:253:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:211:in `to_proc'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:369:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `map'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:369:in `method_missing'
C:/MyApp/app/models/category.rb:24:in `fetch_prices_grouped_by_date'
C:/MyApp/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:103:in `show'
```

I'll investigate it further to see if it's just a specific issue with my code.

**EDIT #2**

Ok, per [this article's](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/10896) recommendation I edited attributes_methods.rb line 252 and changed it from:

```
if self.class.primary_key.to_s == method_name
```

to:

```
if false and self.class.primary_key.to_s == method_name
```

And now it works.
However, not sure I like messing around with the framework's code.
Would appreciate any other suggestions for workarounds.

Thanks!
Amit

**Edit #3**

Ok, this last change broke other parts of my application.
I have reposted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136245/rails-stack-level-too-deep-error-when-calling-id-primary-key-method).

Comment: Right I am having the same exact issue, and my relationship is also called categories. Can it be a naming issue? In the past I've had problems having a field named kind for my models.

Comment: Macario, I don't think it's the naming. Do you have anywhere in your app a Model class which does not derive from ActiveRecord::Base? I think this is my issue. I have a FilterCategory class that has "require 'category'", and I think this messes up the class cache of Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved!
After posting [a third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151264/rails-tableless-model-that-calls-other-models) and with help of [trptcolin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495302/trptcolin), I could confirm a working solution.

The problem: I was using `require` to include models from within Table-less models (classes that are in app/models but do not extend ActiveRecord::Base). For example, I had a class `FilterCategory` that performed `require 'category'`. This messed up with Rails' class caching. 
I had to use `require` in the first place since lines such as `Category.find :all` failed.

The solution (credit goes to trptcolin): replace `Category.find :all` with `::Category.find :all`. This works without the need to explicitly require any model, and therefore doesn't cause any class caching problems.

The "stack too deep" problem also goes away when using `config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc`