# Rails: Tableless model that calls other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with a few model classes (e.g. `Category`, `Subcategory`, `User`, etc.). In order to implement a not-too-trivial filter functionality, I built a hierarchy of filter classes: `FilterCategory`, `FilterSubcategory`, etc., that derive from `FilterBase`. Each of them uses the appropriate "sister" model class (e.g. `Category.find :all`).

I quickly realized that I can't simply call the "sister" model class without using "require" first. However, I now suspect that using "require" is the main reason for two other problems I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130829/each-map-on-array-results-in-you-have-a-nil-object-when-you-didnt-expect-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136245/rails-stack-level-too-deep-error-when-calling-id-primary-key-method), which probably mess up the class caching when `config.cache_classes=false`.

Is there another way for me to call these other models without requiring them?

I tried using the BaseWithoutTable plugin, but when I call the "sister model", I end up getting "Not a valid constant descriptor: nil", which occurs since Rails looks for "`FilterCategory::Category`" rather than "`Category`".

Any thoughts of the best way to do that?

I'm using Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.8.7.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you want `::Category` - getting Category from the top-level namespace rather than scoping it to FilterCategory?

If your models are in the app/models directory, you shouldn't need to explicitly require them - Rails already takes care of that.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thanks trptcolin. You solved me a headache of 2 days.